# hive casting date

Tags: sql, hive

In a hive table I have bunch of date that are in integer format.

Example

Table

```
Date
2015051517
2015051518
2015081517
```

Query

```
SELECT CAST(date TO INT)
FROM date_table;
```

How do I get the above example like below?

```
date
-------------
2015-05 15:17 
2015-05 15:18
2015-08 15:17
```

Thanks in advance!i

Comment: format the date using `to_date`

Comment: Tried this, but gives null values. select to_date('2015051517');

Comment: `select to_date('201505 15:17','YYYY-MM HH24:MI'');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your date columns are in integer datatype, cast them as string and use Hive's built-in date functions.

Here what you need:

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(your-column as string),'yyyyMMHHmm')),'yyyy-MM HH:mm') from table;
```

The above code gave me the following results.

```
2015-05 15:17 
2015-05 15:18
2015-08 15:17
Time taken: 0.088 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```